# On the value of proofs vs counterexamples

Tags: soft-question, alternative-proof

If a conjecture doesn't hold we usually provide a counterexample. While re-proving theorems is valuable and mathematicians do it usually, I think proving that some statement is wrong without giving counterexample rather providing general argument to prove that it is wrong, should also be valuable. However, I have not seen such approaches. Why is that so?

Thank you.

Comment: Most claims have the form "For $x$ statement $P(x)$ holds". The negation of such claim would be: "There exists some $x$ for which $P(x)$ does not holds". So, any valid argument again such claim should includes a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, a proof of such a statement has to prove that a counterexample exists.  However, this may be a *nonconstructive* proof, meaning that it proves counterexamples exist without pinpointing a specific counterexample.  Alex's question below gives an example.

Comment: @Jair Taylor: One important aim of re-proving is to learn more. I think we can learn also when we try to prove that it is not always ....(e.g. Alex's example) by this way: suppose it holds always and arrive to a contradiction. Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: You could disprove a statement that way, but ultimately any proof is logically equivalent to showing that there exists a counterexample, since that's what it means for such a statement to be false.  So either you can trace through the logic of the proof and discover that you essentially found a counterexample in disguise, or else it's really a nonconstructive proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us examine a rather simple statement (which happens to be untrue):

If $n$ is an odd integer, then $n+n$ is likewise odd.

One can "disprove" this, by finding a particular $n$ as a counter-example: in this case $n = 1$ works nicely: $1 = 2\cdot 0 + 1$ is odd, but $1 + 1 = 2$ is even.

However, mathematicians often like to go "even further": and prove a stronger statement (which implies the weaker statement provided by our single counter-example):

If $n$ is an odd integer, $n+n$ is *never* odd.

A somewhat facile, but direct proof: $n+n = 2n$, which is even, and thus not odd.

A more typical approach:

Assume (by way of aiming to show a contradiction), that $n + n = 2k + 1$, for some integer $k$. Then $2(n-k) = 1$, for some integer $n-k$ (since the difference of two integers is an integer).

But clearly, $n - k = \dfrac{1}{2}$, which is not an integer, so we have a contradiction (Note this appeals to the rational numbers, which might be considered "unfair". If one wished to reason entirely within the integers, one would have to show that there is *no* integer $t$ with $2t = 1$. An outline of how one would do this: 1) show $t > 0$, 2) show $t < 1$, 3) conclude there is no such integer $t$).

A caveat: it may be that there is actually only *one* counter-example (something might be true for all natural numbers $n > 1$, but not for $1$ itself), that is, something is "almost true" (and can be turned into a true statement, with a minor modification). For example, there are a whole slew of mathematical statements involving "odd primes" (because $2$ is the only counter-example when considering a statement about *all* primes that is untrue for even primes).

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean; restating the argument as you did; turning it to a true statement then proving it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My personal favorite: Do there exist irrationals, $a,b$ such that $a^b$ is rational? In terms of your question, the conjecture is that there do not exist $a,b$ such that $a^b$ is rational. This conjecture is false as shown below by contradiction:

Look at $(\sqrt{2})^{\sqrt{2}}$. If it's rational we're done. Otherwise it's irrational and $((\sqrt{2})^{\sqrt{2}})^{\sqrt{2}}=2$. So either $a=b=\sqrt{2}$ or $a=(\sqrt{2})^{\sqrt{2}}$,$b=\sqrt{2}$ give an answer. It's up to you to figure out which one is right!

Comment: For this example, my question would be: Prove that we can't write $a^b$ as $\dfrac{p}{q}$ if we can't write $a$ and $b$ in form of $\dfrac{p}{q}$; without giving an example!

Comment: @AlphaE: Your reformulation is false. But maybe that is what you meant. As mentioned, to disprove it one has to prove the existence of some counter-example.

Comment: No, @AlphaE, Alex just demonstrated that we *may* do that.  There exists an $a^b$ that is rational when neither $a$ nor $b$ are.  We just don't know which it is.

Answer (score 1):

Your statements are not true. If the conjecture is of the form "There exists a $T$ such that $P$", then to prove it you must prove that there is at least one $T$ such that $P$ holds (this may or may not be an explicit example), and to disprove it you do not give any counter-example whatsoever, but must rather prove that "For any $T$, $P$ does not hold.". Some examples:

1. There exists a largest integer. False, and proven by showing that for any integer there is a larger one.
2. There exists a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is not differentiable at any point. True, and proven by constructing such a function (two examples are the Weierstrass function and the Blancmange curve)
3. There exists a monotonic function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is discontinuous at uncountably many points. False, and proven by showing that every such function is discontinuous only at countably many points.

But it is true that we like certain kinds of theorems. As *user251257* said, many conjectures are of the form "For any ..., ...". This arises naturally because we want to be able to say as much as we can, so of course we would like to have universal quantification. But as you can see from the second example above, we also have some theorems that just assert the existence of a single object.

Comment: In some cases you can prove that there exists a $T$ such that $P$ holds without giving a specific example.

Comment: @DavidZ: Of course. Did my answer imply otherwise?

Comment: Yes, it does. The second sentence says that you must give an example of a $T$ such that $P$ holds to prove the conjecture.

Comment: @DavidZ: Okay I'll edit it, but I did not mean "explicit example". In terms of logic, once existence is proven we can instantiate it. But thanks for being such a careful reader!

Comment: You're welcome :-) I guess this idea, that once existence is proven you can provide an instance, is not something I accept, at least not in general. In the usage I'm familiar with, merely showing that an example of something exists does not count as giving an example of that thing.

Comment: @DavidZ: Then you may have to think more carefully about the logical underpinnings of your everyday mathematical work. For example, when you write something like "Let $x = y + z$", you are already invoking an existential instantiation. If you only have the successor function, every other function requires instantiation even if you do not count function application. It gets worse with ZFC where every set constructed is an existential instantiation based on the ZFC axioms. If you use something completely different like dependent type theory, then such distinctions become more meaningful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25806/discussion-between-david-z-and-user21820).

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, having a specific counterexample can help you understand why a statement isn't true. I believe there's some evidence that inductive reasoning by synthesizing examples is a particularly natural way for most people to think, and thus an example or two can often contribute more to intuitive understanding of a problem than a fully general proof.

Given that counterexamples are desirable, the only cases where it really makes sense not to give a counterexample are those where it's infeasible to come up with one in the first place. I would imagine those cases are relatively uncommon.